# @WebServlet with GlassFish server

Tags: java, servlets, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, servlet-3.0

The `@WebServlet` annotation has also this keys:

`displayName`, `smallIcon`, `largeIcon`, `description`

but after setting these attributes where can I get or see them?

Comment: What about key `urlPatterns`? E. g. `urlPatterns={"/MyServlet"}` will make servlet available at http[s]://yourhost[:port]/[appContext]/MyServlet

Answer (score 5):

These properties can be used by the servlet container's administration tools but containers are free to just ignore them.

These properties mirror entries in the web.xml. See the relevant schemas for documentation.